# React Native Firebase starter and React Navigation

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-navigation, react-native-firebase

I want to use the [react native firebase starter template](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-starter) and add [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org).

I have got the *react-native-firebase-starter* project up and running and have linked it to firebase. But now when I follow the steps to add *react-navigation* I come into problems with `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`.

I guessed because the project uses cocoa pods and this command adds a line to the Podfile, that I should `cd ios` and run `pod install`.

The problem then is that I get an error: **`[!] React has been deprecated`** and the project won't build.

Has anyone successfully used this starter project and added *react-navigation* to it?

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong or what to do to get it sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

You need to add these lines into your app target in the Podfile...

```
pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
```

And then at the very bottom of the Podfile you need to add the following...

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    targets_to_ignore = %w(React yoga)
    if targets_to_ignore.include? target.name
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

This removes React & Yoga from the Pods project, as it is already included in the main project.